# CRM Filtered Views Finds No Results

Tags: filter, dynamics-crm, criteria

I am having a problem searching on full address in the lookup field on an entity for properties that we have created. I can type in the number of the address (e.g. 48) and it brings all the "48's" back. As soon as I write "48 name of street" it brings back nothing.

[image]

If I type "48 *name of address" it finds it.

[image]

but there are not any other words, spaces or special characters between the 48 and the name of street. Searching on the reference of the property finds it immediately. here is the filter criteria setup.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: What results do you get if you search for the name of the street? Can you do an Advanced Search for the record using "48 Name of street"?

Comment: same issue. its weird

Comment: The filter is set to return all active records. Can you verify that the entity you are trying to search for is actually active?

Comment: Can you show exactly what is saved in the field? (Use a dummy value, if you can't show production data).

Comment: it would be '48 Street Name' with link to property entity.

Comment: added new image at the end of the post

Comment: Everything seems to be setup correctly. I cannot access my CRM right now to try it out. I will try to do it later, if you haven't found a solution yet.

Comment: One last thought - is the address of the Property entity a "Composite field", such as the address for a Contact, or is it a "Single line of text"-field?

Comment: single line of text, but we do populate that with data from another ingres database using middleware. Im starting to think the problem may lie in whats being migrated, special characters? checking that now.

Answer (score 1):

turns out it was our middleware software scribe. There was a space within a trim enclosure, which should have removed the space but didnt. thank you Lars anyway.

Comment: I'm happy you fixed the issue. From your descriptions it seemed that everything is setup correctly in CRM, so it makes sense that the problem was elsewhere, and it was only the "symptom" showing in CRM.